# AS3: Any chance using cairo graphics lib from as3? Through Alchemy?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, cairo

I haven't seen any port of the cairo graphics library to AS3.
Would it be possible to implement cairo solutions through Alchemy?
Other possibilities?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve using cairo?

Comment: Hi grapefrukt! I'm working on a music notation solution where it is important to be able to render for high quality printing and graphic files (including pdf, svg, png).

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but an interesting factoid: Flash actually uses libcairo and libpangocairo for 2D rendering (ldd a flashplayer binary on Linux if you don't believe me :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... No fish in the AS3/Alchemy net. It seems like handling the Cairo stuff on the server is the best way to go right now. The PHP native Cairo extension will be a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the spark skinning and drawing style.

Comment: Hi Adrian! Spark skinning and drawing style to use cario in AS3..? Don't think so... I guess that you answered another question: "How do I draw graphic primitives in Flex?" or something like that... :-)

Comment: All I wanted to say is to use something else instead. I think there is no cairo library in as3. Also you may want to check out degrafa. maybe that cal help you.. or not!?   anyway I just love spending my time trying to help people and getting -minus  ratings. But that's how people are >:-|

Comment: Hi Adrian! The reason I asked for cairo is... well, cairo! One single solution to handle top quality pdf, svg, bitmaps etc. As3/Flex solutions (including FXG and Degrafa) are great for handling on-screen stuff, and my needs go beyond that.

Comment: then google about degrafa and svg. you may need to create your own degrafa tp svg converter. :(   http://code.google.com/p/degrafa/issues/detail?id=49&can=1&q=DegrafaMap.mxml

Comment: Hello aganin, Adrian! Thank you about your information and concerns in this! :-) Still, the reason that I asked for a port of, or a way to use, Cairo is Cairo! When I ask for Cairo, why should I google for Degrafa? :-) Sorry for minus rating (a bit of overreacting from my side). I just made sure that you got an extra plus for another of your answers! Cheers!